# (Beginner) Which Python regular expression can be used to extract a 3-tuple like (125, 8, 1212) from the following string?

Tags: python, regex

```
<div>125mm x 8mm x 1212mm</div>
```

This is the following string!

Comment: ```re.findall(r'\d+','<div>125mm x 8mm x 1212mm</div>')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
x=tuple(int(j) for j in re.findall(r'\d+','<div>125mm x 8mm x 1212mm</div>'))
print(x)
# (125, 8, 1212)
```